# Write to a Remote file with Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying to backup databases and move them around to different servers using [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html).

When on a remote server, to open a file for writing it fails with the error.

```
newFile = open('%s%s' % (dumpPath,newFileName) ,'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ec2-user/dbbackup.sql.bz2'
```

That files exists, and I even tried creating beforehand just in case fabric didnt have permissions to create, but it still didnt work

```
 run("touch dbbackup.sql.bz2")
```

EDIT: I know that I can upload files on to a remote server but thats not what I am trying to do with the open command. I am trying to compress a large file (a database dump) Is it possible to do this on the remote server, or would I have to copy the DB dump to the local host, compress there and then upload back. Here is compression on local host:

```
compObj= bz2.BZ2Compressor()
newFile = open('%s%s' % (dumpPath,newFileName) ,'w')
dbFile = file( '%s%s' % (dumpPath,filename), "r" )
block= dbFile.read( BLOCK_SIZE )
while True: #write the compressed data
        cBlock= compObj.compress( block )
        newFile.write(cBlock)
        block= dbFile.read( BLOCK_SIZE )
        if not block:
            break
    cBlock= compObj.flush()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you can open a file remotely. But even if you can, it may not be a good idea in your case, since you will be fetching the large file over ssh (remember that Fabric is still running on your local machine). Why not compress the file remotely, and then get the compressed file?   In case of mysqldump, it would look like this:

```
run('mysqldump [options] | gzip > outputfile.sql.gz')
get('outputfile.sql.gz')
```

(more on mysqldump and gzip here: [Compressing mysqldump output](http://www.ducea.com/2006/10/28/compressing-mysqldump-output/) )

Comment: thanks, was trying to do the compression with python, but using gzip works just fine as well.

Answer (score 7):

In Fabric, you are never "on a remote server". Some Fabric commands run locally, and some run on the remote server. In this case, you are using Python's `open` function, which tries to open the file on your local computer, and understandably fails.  You can use Fabric's [put and get functions](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/api/core/operations.html) to move files between your local computer and the remote server.

Comment: Thanks for posting a link. Please see my updated question. Can I open and add to a file remotely with data on the remote host or do I need to copy back and forth

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to read the Fabric tutorial again.
2. You should be using os.path.join to assemble your filepath.
3. That open() call is trying to open the file on your local machine, NOT the remote server.